# Noether's charge due to lorentz transformation

Tags: special-relativity, noethers-theorem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What conservation law corresponds to Lorentz boosts?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12559/what-conservation-law-corresponds-to-lorentz-boosts)

For a relativistic free particle, What is the Noether charge generated due to Lorentz transformations? What is conserved quantity associated with boosts?

Comment: Boosts do not commute with Hamiltonian so there can be no conserved quantity corresponding to them.

Comment: @dushya The answer in the duplicate question seems to indicate that it is t*p-x*E

Comment: Hmm.. I think Noether charge corresponding to a continuous symmetry of action is just the generator of that symmetry. Whether it is conserved or not depends upon whether it commutes with Hamiltonian or not. The Noether charge corresponding to boosts doesn't commute with Hamiltonian and hence changes with time.