# Question about Noether theorem

Tags: symmetry, noethers-theorem

For the Noether theorem for pseudoeuclidean 4-spacetime a-current $J_{a}^{\mu}$ is equal to

$$
J_{a}^{\mu} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_{\mu}\Psi_{k})}Y_{k, a} - \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_{\mu}\Psi_{k})}\partial_{\nu}\Psi_{k} - \delta_{\nu}^{\mu}L \right) X_{a}^{\nu}, 
$$

$$
\quad Y_{k, a} = \left(\frac{\partial F_{k}(\Psi , \omega)}{\partial \omega^{a}}\right)_{\omega = 0}, \quad X_{a}^{\nu} = \left(\frac{\partial f^{\nu}(x , \omega)}{\partial \omega^{a}}\right)_{\omega = 0},
$$

$F_{k}$ - function of field transformation, $f^{\nu}$ - function of coordinates transformation, $ \omega^{a}$ - parameter of transformation.

The charge is equal to 
$$
\partial_{\mu}J_{a}^{\mu} = 0 \Rightarrow Q_{a} = \int J_{a}^{0} (t, \mathbf r)d^{3}\mathbf r .
$$

How to "reduce" the number of dimentions in this theorem for euclidean 3-space (i.e. get the formulation of theorem for euclidean space)?

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): Noether's theorem can be formulated in any number of spacetime dimensions independently. Why do you want to perform a dimensional reduction?

Comment: I want to see what the integral corresponds of symmetry of the Galilean transformations.

Comment: And I don't want to formulate theorem for 3-dimensional euclidean space.

Comment: The Noether charges for Lorentz transformations are e.g. treated  in [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12559/2451) Phys.SE post. The Noether charges for Galilean transformations are e.g. mentioned on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem).