# What is the invariant associated with the symmetry of boosts?

Tags: symmetry, noethers-theorem

Noether's Theorem states that if a Lagrangian is symmetric for a certain transformation, this leads to an invariant: Symmetry of translation gives momentum conservation, Symmetry of time  gives Energy conservation etc.

The Galilean principle stating that all reference frames that move with constant speed relative to each other are equivalent is also a symmetry principle: Setting up a physical system that is identical to the original except for a constant velocity (boost) added will have the same behaviour.

Shouldn't there be an invariant associated with this symmetry? If yes, what is that invariant?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12559/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The conserved quantity corresponding to boost symmetry is 
$$
\int d^3 x (P_0 x_i - P_i t)
$$
which is the relativistic analogue of $x_{CM} - v_{CM} t$, the position of the center of mass at $t=0$. It is quite a useless conserved quantity, and that is why people don't talk about it.

Comment: Is this quantity always zero?

Comment: No. It is the position of the center of mass at $t=0$.

Comment: There's a formal similarity to the expression for angular momentum. Not surprising as boosts are a kind of rotation.

Comment: But if the center of mass is moving, then the position of center of mass at t = 0 will be moving away, i.e. changing, in the reference frame attached to the center of mass.

Comment: No. The position at $t=0$ (at a specific time) does not change. The position changes as a function of time though.

Comment: If something changes as a function of time, how can it be considered an invariant? By that logic, at  t=0, everything would qualify as an invariant (at that specific moment).

Comment: Right. That's the reason this conserved quantity is useless. Its simply telling us that the center of mass at time $t=0$ is preserved. But that is obviously true!

Comment: The conserved quantities under rotations are the 3 components of angular momentum around a point, in space (any point if space is homogeneous).  The conserved quantities under Lorentz boosts are the 3 components of "angular momentum" around an instant, in space-time.  That instant is any time $t$, not just $t = 0$.

Comment: I think P0 should be replaced by P0/c^2 since it represents the inertial mass, not the energy.

Comment: It is not a useless quantity, it is simply obvious. It says a particle's position moves in accordance with its linear momentum. Otherwise it would be a mess!

Comment: @SergioPrats we only work in natural units here.

Comment: This equation tells that the overall flow of energy is determined by the overall momentum in the system and for an isolated system it is a conserved quantity. I wonder if there is a similar equation for the "flow of momentum" that is caused by momentum moving itself or by the stresses (see Maxwell tensor), if it exists it should be associated with some symmetry.