# Poincare Generators in terms of Position and Momentum

Tags: quantum-field-theory, angular-momentum, momentum, lie-algebra, poincare-symmetry

The $10$ generators of the Poincare group $P(1;3)$ are $M^{\mu\nu}$ and $P^\mu$. These generators can be determined explicitly in the matrix form. However, I have found that $M^{\mu\nu}$ and $P^\mu$ are often written in terms of position $x^\mu$ and momentum $p^\mu$ as

$$ M^{\mu\nu} = x^\mu p^\nu - x^\nu p^\mu $$
and
$$ P^\mu = p^\mu$$

How do we get these relations?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12559/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One obtains those expressions by considering a particular action of the Poincare group on fields.

Consider, for example, a single real scalar field $\phi:\mathbb R^{3,1}\to\mathbb R$.  Let $\mathcal F$ denote the space of such fields.  Define an action $\rho_\mathcal F$ of $P(3,1)$ acting on $\mathcal F$ as follows
\begin{align}
  \rho_\mathcal F(\Lambda,a)(\phi)(x) = \phi(\Lambda^{-1} (x-a))
\end{align}
Sometimes people will write this as $\phi'(x) = \phi(\Lambda^{-1} x)$ for brevity.  Now let $G$ denote a generator of the Lie algebra of the Poincare group (namely an element of a chosen basis for this Lie algebra).  We can use this generator to define a corresponding infinitesimal generator for group action $\rho_\mathcal F$ as follows:
\begin{align}
  G_\mathcal F(\phi) = i\frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon}\rho_\mathcal F(e^{-i\epsilon G})(\phi)\bigg|_{\epsilon = 0}
\end{align}

**Example - translations.** Consider the translation generators $P^\mu$ which have the property
\begin{align}
  e^{-ia_\mu P^\mu}x = x+a
\end{align}
The generator of $\rho_\mathcal F$ corresponding to $P^0$, for instance, is
\begin{align}
  (P^0)_\mathcal F(\phi)(x) 
&= i\frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon}\rho_\mathcal F(e^{-i\epsilon P^0})(\phi)\bigg|_{\epsilon = 0} \\
&= i\frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon}\phi(x + \epsilon e_0)\bigg|_{\epsilon = 0} \\
&= i\partial^0\phi(x)
\end{align}
where $e_0 = (1,0,0,0)$, and similarly for the other $P^\mu$, which gives
\begin{align}
  (P^\mu)_\mathcal F = i\partial^\mu.
\end{align}

**Example - Lorentz boosts.**

If you use this same procedure for Lorentz boost generators, you will find that
\begin{align}
  (M^{\mu\nu})_\mathcal F = i(x^\mu\partial^\nu - x^\nu\partial^\mu) = x^\mu p^\nu - x^\nu p^\mu
\end{align}

**Disclaimer about signs etc.** There are a lot of conventional factors of $i$ and negative signs floating around which I wasn't super careful to keep track of, if you notice an error in this regard, please let me know and I'll fix it.

Comment: Can you please tell me what the commutation relation is: $[x^\mu, P^\nu] = ?$

Comment: @Ome Since that's a distinct question and would be useful for other users, you should ask it in another post!

Answer (score 3):

The generators of isometry, also generators of the Poincare group, are the Killing vectors, hence we need the Killing vectors of Minkowski spacetime, $ds^2 = -dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2+ dz^2$. The defining equation of the Killing vectors in terms of their components ($\xi = \xi^\mu \partial_\mu$ is a Killing vector with components $\xi^\mu$) is $$\partial_{(\mu} \xi_{\nu)}=0,$$ where the parentheses denote symmetrization over the enclosed indices. We differentiate once, then cyclically permute the indices, $$\begin{split}\partial_c\partial_a \xi_b + \partial_b\partial_c \xi_a &=0,\\
\partial_a\partial_b\xi_c + \partial_c\partial_a\xi_b&= 0,\\
\partial_b\partial_c\xi_a + \partial_a\partial_b\xi_c &=0,\end{split}$$ which is a linear system with unknowns $\partial_a\partial_b\xi_c$ and its permutations. The only solution of the system is the trivial $\partial_a\partial_b\xi_c=0$, from which we obtain $\xi_a = a_{ab} x^b + b_a$ with $a_{ab}$ and $b_a$ constants. From the defining equation we obtain $a_{ab} = -a_{ba}$ and, since the Killing vectors are unique up to multiplication with a constant and translation, we obtain $$    \begin{aligned}
      \partial_{t} && \partial_{x} && \partial_{y} && \partial_{z},\\
      -x\partial_{t} - t\partial_{x}, && -y\partial_{t} -
      t \partial_{y} && - z\partial_{y} - t\partial_{z},\\
      x\partial_{y} - y\partial_{x} && y\partial_{z} - z\partial_{x} &&
      z\partial_{x} - x \partial_{z}.&&
    \end{aligned}$$
On the first line are the translation generators, on the second the boost generators and on the third the rotation generators.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following transform, given in infinitesimal form, on coordinates $(,t,u)$, where $ = (x,y,z)$, by
$$Δ = × - t + ,\quad Δt = -α· + τ,\quad Δu = · + ψ,$$
where $(,)$ are identified, respectively, as an infinitesimal rotation and boost and $(,τ,ψ)$ as infinitesimal translations on the coordinates. This is actually a one-parameter family of transforms, parametrized by $α$.

We'll see what that means in a moment. It is connected to the following. For coordinate differentials, we have the transforms:
$$Δd = ×d - dt,\quad Δdt = -α·d,\quad Δdu = ·d.$$
Out of this arise two invariants:
$$|d|^2 + 2 dt du + α(du)^2,\quad ds = dt + αdu,\quad (s ≡ t + αu).$$

Let the coordinate transforms be written as Poisson brackets
$$Δ(\_) = \left\{\_,Λ\right\},\quad Λ = · + · + · - τH + ψμ.$$
Then we have the following associations:
$$\begin{align}
Λ
&⇔ -(× - t + )·∇ - (-α· + τ)\frac{∂}{∂t} - (· + ψ)\frac{∂}{∂u}\\
&= ·(-×∇) + ·\left(t∇ + \left(α\frac{∂}{∂t} - \frac{∂}{∂u}\right)\right) + ·(-∇) - τ\left(\frac{∂}{∂t}\right) + ψ\left(-\frac{∂}{∂u}\right).
\end{align}$$
Component-by-component, this leads to the following associations:
$$
 ⇔ -×∇,\quad
 ⇔ t∇ + \left(α\frac{∂}{∂t} - \frac{∂}{∂u}\right),\quad
 ⇔ -∇,\quad
H ⇔ \frac{∂}{∂t},\quad
μ ⇔ -\frac{∂}{∂u}.
$$

Defining the relations
$$\left\{x^a,x^b\right\} = 0,\quad \left\{x^a,\frac{∂}{∂x^b}\right\} = -δ^a_b,\quad \left\{\frac{∂}{∂x^a},x^b\right\} = δ^b_a,\quad \left\{\frac{∂}{∂x^a},\frac{∂}{∂x^b}\right\} = 0,$$
we can treat the associations as identities
$$
 = -×∇,\quad
 = t∇ + \left(α\frac{∂}{∂t} - \frac{∂}{∂u}\right),\quad
 = -∇,\quad
H = \frac{∂}{∂t},\quad
μ = -\frac{∂}{∂u},
$$
and write down the following brackets:
$$
\left\{J_i,J_j\right\} = ε^k_{ij}J_k,\quad
\left\{J_i,K_j\right\} = ε^k_{ij}K_k,\quad
\left\{J_i,P_j\right\} = ε^k_{ij}P_k,\\
\left\{K_i,K_j\right\} = -αε^k_{ij}J_k,\quad
\left\{K_i,P_j\right\} = δ_{ij}M,\quad
\left\{P_i,P_j\right\} = 0,\\
\left\{J_i,H\right\} = 0,\quad
\left\{K_i,H\right\} = P_i,\quad
\left\{P_i,H\right\} = 0,\\
\left\{J_i,μ\right\} = 0,\quad
\left\{K_i,μ\right\} = 0,\quad
\left\{P_i,μ\right\} = 0,\quad
\left\{H,μ\right\} = 0,\quad
M ≡ μ + αH.
$$
This is a one-parameter family of Lie algebras, with the only dependency on the parameter $α$ being with the $\left\{K,K\right\}$ and $\left\{K,P\right\}$ brackets.

From these, we can also write down the following identity for $M$:
$$M = α\frac{∂}{∂t} - \frac{∂}{∂u},$$
and the following brackets for $M$:
$$
\left\{J_i,M\right\} = 0,\quad
\left\{K_i,M\right\} = αP_i,\quad
\left\{P_i,M\right\} = 0,\quad
\left\{H,M\right\} = 0,\quad
\left\{μ,M\right\} = 0.
$$

In the case $α = 0$, it is the Lie algebra for the Galilei group, lifted to the Bargmann group by central extension with the central charge $μ$. Both $M$ and $μ$ coincide and correspond to the mass. The geometric invariants reduce to:
$$dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 + 2 dt du,\quad ds = dt,$$
the roles played by $s$ and $t$ coincide and correspond to time, as well as to "proper time".

The generators correspond to angular momentum $$, moment $$, linear momentum $$, kinetic(+internal) energy $H$ and mass $M = μ$.

In the case $α > 0$, the quadratic invariant may be rewritten by substituting $u$ by $s$, as:
$$dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 - \frac{dt^2}{α} + \frac{ds^2}{α}.$$
If we continue to identify the invariant $ds$ as the differential for proper time, and set the quadratic invariant to 0, then the result will be a reduction to the geometry given by:
$$ds^2 = dt^2 - α\left(dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2\right).$$
This is the Minkowski metric, written as an absolute time metric, where $α = 1/c^2$, and $c$ is the in-vacuo speed of light.

The Lie algebra is a deformation of the Bargmann group at $α = 0$, to a 1-generator extension of the Poincaré group at $α = 1/c^2 > 0$.

Perform the corresponding substitutions on the differential operators:
$$\left(\frac{∂}{∂t}\right)_u = \left(\frac{∂}{∂s}\right)_t +  \left(\frac{∂}{∂t}\right)_s,\quad \left(\frac{∂}{∂u}\right)_t = α\left(\frac{∂}{∂s}\right)_t\quad⇒\quad α\left(\frac{∂}{∂t}\right)_u - \left(\frac{∂}{∂u}\right)_t = α\left(\frac{∂}{∂t}\right)_s.
$$
This leads to the following revised identities:
$$
 = -×∇,\quad
 = t∇ + α\frac{∂}{∂t},\quad
 = -∇,\quad
H = \frac{∂}{∂s} + \frac{∂}{∂t},\quad
μ = -α\frac{∂}{∂s},\quad
M = α\frac{∂}{∂t}.
$$
The generator $M$ now plays the role of "moving mass" and is usually written as "total energy" $E = Mc^2$, i.e. $M = αE$.

The Lie algebra splits into two subalgebras generated respectively by $(,,,E)$ - the Lie algebra for the Poincaré group - and $(μ)$, where $(H,M)$ are replaced by $(E,μ)$. The generator for Poincaré group Lie algebra reduce to:
$$
 = -×∇,\quad
 = t∇ + α\frac{∂}{∂t},\quad
 = -∇,\quad
E = \frac{∂}{∂t}.
$$
Adopting the coordinates $\left(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3\right) = (ct,x,y,z)$, now with $c = 1/\sqrt{α}$, and writing $∂_a = ∂/∂x^a$, the generators can be written as:
$$
 = \left(x^3 ∂_2 - x^2 ∂_3, x^1 ∂_3 - x^3 ∂_1, x^2 ∂_1 - x^1 ∂_2\right),\\
c = \left(x^0 ∂_1 + x^1 ∂_0, x^0 ∂_2 + x^2 ∂_0, x^0 ∂_3 + x^3 ∂_0\right),\\
\frac{E}{c} = ∂_0,\quad  = \left(-∂_1, -∂_2, -∂_3\right).
$$

With respect to the metric, rewritten as
$$d(cs)^2 = d(ct)^2 - dx^2 - dy^2 - dz^2,$$
the indices raise as
$$\left(∂^0,∂^1,∂^2,∂^3\right) = \left(∂_0,-∂_1,-∂_2,-∂_3\right),$$
so that we can write:
$$
 = \left(x^2 ∂^3 - x^3 ∂^2, x^3 ∂^1 - x^1 ∂^3, x^1 ∂^2 - x^2 ∂^1\right),\\
c = \left(x^1 ∂^0 - x^0 ∂^1, x^2 ∂^0 - x^0 ∂^2, x^3 ∂^0 - x^0 ∂^3\right),\\
\frac{E}{c} = ∂^0,\quad  = \left(∂^1, ∂^2, ∂^3\right).
$$

Unlike the previous expressions, though, this depends on which convention is adopted for the metric. If the opposite signs are used
$$dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 - d(ct)^2 = -d(cs)^2,$$
then all the signs for the index-raised forms of $∂^a$ in $(,c,,E/c)$ will flip.