# Conserved charge for boosts?

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, group-theory

In (3+1) dimension Poincare group has three types of Symmetries :

a) Four space-time translations 
b) Three spatial rotations and
c) Three boosts

Among them, (a) implies "conservation of 4-momentum" , 
(b) implies "conservation of angular momentum" ,

But what "Physical" (if any) entity is conserved for boosts??

Comment: This question was asked before: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12559/

Comment: wow! thannks a lot @MengCheng.. :)