# Does spin generate rotation in ordinary 3-dimensional space?

Tags: angular-momentum, quantum-spin, field-theory, noethers-theorem, lorentz-symmetry

*Angular momenta* are the *generators of rotations*. The orbital angular momentum, denoted by $\textbf{L}=(L_1,L_2,L_3)$, generates rotations in three-dimensional space in the planes $xy$, $yz$, $zx$ respectively.

The Spin $\textbf{S}=(S_1,S_2,S_3)$ also represents angular momentum which is *intrinsic* in nature. Being an angular momentum, it is also a generator rotation. *But do they also generate ordinary rotation in 3-dimensional space?*

Comment: The spin operators also generates rotations in the three regular dimensions, it is just that they are used to rotate spinors, rather than regular vectors.

Comment: @SRS I am also now considering a similar problem. For me, rotation and boost are related with SU(2) and SL(2) operations, which can both be regarded as operations on a spin or a qubit. Obviously they lead to invariant Minkovski metric. If we further generate the single qubit/spin operation to double qubit operations ($GL(4)$), we will get general GR metric tensor. So I am thinking how 2 qubit operations are related with spacetime structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I) The main point is that when we apply [Noether's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether's_theorem) for a field theory, the 
total angular momentum Noether current

$$J^{\mu,\nu\lambda}~=~L^{\mu,\nu\lambda}+S^{\mu,\nu\lambda}$$

splits in an orbital angular momentum current $$L^{\mu,\nu\lambda}=x^{\nu}T^{\mu,\lambda}-(\nu\leftrightarrow \lambda)$$

and an internal spin angular momentum Noether current $$S^{\mu,\nu\lambda}~=~\frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial \Phi_{,\mu}} \Sigma^{\nu\lambda}\Phi,$$

where $\Sigma^{\nu\lambda}$ furnishes a Lorentz representation of the field $\Phi$ in the field target space. For further details, see e.g. Ref. 1.

II) In particular for a scalar field theory, there is no spin, $\Sigma^{\nu\lambda}=0$ is generators for the trivial representation, and the angular momentum is generated purely from infinitesimal variations in spacetime, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12559/2451) Phys.SE post.

References:

1. A. Bandyopadhyay, [*Improvement of the Stress-Energy Tensor using Spacetime symmetries*](http://research.physics.illinois.edu/Publications/theses/copies/Bandyopadhyay/), PhD thesis (2001); Chapter 2.