# What physical quantity is spin a generator of?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, observables

I know, we do not have an classical analog for the concept of spin in quantum mechanics. But, consider the following, Any infinitesimal operator we have:
$$U_{\epsilon}=\mathbb{I}-i\hat{G}\epsilon$$
where, for the infinitesimal translation:
$$\hat{G}\rightarrow\frac{\hat{p}}{\hbar}$$
Similarly, for an infinitesimal rotation, by analogy, we have the angular momentum operator.
Now, for a spin system, what is it a generator of?

Comment: possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/210626/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/407116/50583

Comment: maybe my answer here will help https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/620305/