# Poincaré group conservation laws: 10 of 7?

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem, poincare-symmetry

According to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_group) about the Poincaré group, we get 10 conservation laws using Noethers theorem.

> 10 generators (in four spacetime dimensions) associated with the Poincaré symmetry, by Noether's theorem, imply 10 conservation laws:
>
> - 1 for the energy – associated with translations through time
> - 3 for the momentum – associated with translations through spatial dimensions
> - 3 for the angular momentum – associated with rotations between spatial dimensions
> - 3 for the velocity of the center of mass – associated with hyperbolic rotations between each spatial dimension and time

It seems to me that these reduce to just 7 conservation laws. Because velocity conservation of the center of mass is equivalent to momentum conservation. But why would 10 distinct symmetries only yield 7 distict conservation laws? Am I missing something?

Comment: The wording from wikipedia does sound misleading, but the last three are meant to be the conservations associated with boosts.  See these [prior](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12559/307551) [phys.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71641/) [questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/259311/).

Comment: Thank you! That answers my question

Comment: As @Marek answers in the first of those links, the conserved quantity associated to boosts is the "center of mass at time $t=0$". Maybe you can study that answer and then adjust the wikipedia text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What conservation law corresponds to Lorentz boosts?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12559/168783)

Comment: @BenH I do not understand Marek's answer, but the answer of NinjaDarth seems more straightforward to me. It seems that this is a relativistic quantum effect, but I am not sure.