# Is there a formal distinction between Lorentz boosts and the others types of transformations of the Poincaré group?

Tags: special-relativity, conservation-laws, poincare-symmetry

The doubt arises as space translations can be associated to homogeneity of space, time translations to homogeneity of time and classical rotations to isotropy of space. These properties of space leads to conservation laws of energy, total momentum and angular momentum for isolated systems, but there isn't an analogue property of space related to Lorentz boost.

Infact the conserved quantity associated to boost invariance of the system ([which is presented here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12559/what-conservation-law-corresponds-to-lorentz-boosts)) in general isn't conserved by an isolated system.

This result is present even in the Poincaré algebra, as considered the following commutations rules
$$[H, P^{\mu}]=0$$
$$[H, J^{i}]=0$$
$$[H, K^i]=-iP^i$$
The generators of the translations and classical rotations commute with the hamiltonian, but the generators of boosts doesn't.

To be clear, I am not saying that these results are wrong, these are the properties of spacetime and that's how it is. I am just trying to understand if there is a formal distinction between the boosts and the others transformations, because of the absence of a spacetime "property" (like isotropy or homogeneity) associated to boosts.
Thanks a lot

Comment: FWIW, if we perform a boost, we don't expect the energy to be the same.

Comment: Yes I didn't mean to say that, as if I considere a boosted frame of reference for example the velocity of a particle vary and so the energy. If there is a part of the question that seems to indicate this, please let me know that I'll try to change it.

Comment: You have understood [this](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/boosts.html) and are still unhappy?

Comment: Have you learned about [hyperbolic rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_mapping#Group_theory)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the references. The first link is pretty clear, the meaning of the quantity conserved under lorentz boost is clear. The part which could have a relevance for the question I think is the fact that there isn't an invariant way to separate rotations and boosts (as energy and momentum), hence maybe the fact that I am distinguishing them could be relevant. About the second link, even though I have never studied that topic formaly is quite clear, Boosts can be viewed as "hyperbolic rotations", and these transformations squezze the different regions of the light-cone withouth mixing.

Comment: What I am trying to understand is not the difference between a rotation and boost (the question title may be misleading). I am more interested in the fact that while classical rotations and its quantity conserved (if there is invariance) can be associated to the property of isotropy of the space, while for boosts there isn't an analogue property of the space ( i.e for example, in a non rigorous terminology a kind of "isotropy" that reflects the simmetry of space under both classical rotations and boosts). But to be clear I am not questioning the simmetry of the space.

Comment: I am trying just to understand if there is a formal distinction between boosts and the others types of transformations related to the fact that boosts don't have an analogue of the isotropy or homogeneity properties associated. The fact that a boost is different from a rotation is perfectly clear. Hope my doubt is clear, and thanks a lot for the help

Comment: The invariance property associated to the boost transformation exists but it is not stated separately in space or time as homogeneity and isotropy. It needs the complete spacetime structure to be stated. It is the invariance of physical laws (or of the spacetime) under pure Lorentz transformations along any fixed direction.

Comment: It is exactly as in classical physics where in addition to space and time homogeneity and spatial isotropy there is also the invariance under change of inertial reference frame ( without rotations or spacetime translations).

Comment: The boost symmetry just refers to  the equivalence of all inertial reference frames when  one has already taken into account isotropy and homogeneity.

Comment: This is a fundamental physical fact logically independent  of  the other invariance properties, since they were also valid in the pre Galilean physics, where the equivalence of inertial reference frames was not assumed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Valter Moretti. The fact that simmetry of physical laws under change of frames (given by Lorentz transformation) is clear, even though to me it seems as a simmetry of a different "kind" from the one associated to isotrpy and homogeneity. But to be completely sure when you say "invariance of physical laws (or of the spacetime)" with the specification in the bracket do you mean the invariance of the metric?

Comment: Because in this way this kind of invariance as of the whole spacetime it seems more similar to the other properties of space and time stated separately. Thanks a lot again